# Email field Validation in Site.com form

Tags: site.com

So I've got a site.com form that is submitting to a custom object, and then forwarding to a "thank you" page. This is all standard functionality.

What I am having trouble with is the following:

I have an email field on the custom object, and a field on the site.com form that maps to it. This field is required. However, when a user types in something that isn't a valid email address, instead of giving a nice popup error like it does when you don't fill out a required field, the site hides the form and displays the error:

Error
We're unable to retrieve your data due to an error.

I'm 100% sure that this is happening due to the invalid email.

What I don't know is how to get the form to validate the email format before saving to the database, and displaying a more user-friendly form validation experience.

Comment: This doesn't address the validation, but you can change the error message by changing the [Error View](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_data_views.htm&language=en_US).  It'd be nice if Site.com had behavior such as displaying an error message returned from the submission or something to that effect, but I don't think it does.